# How to do null check of each element in JSONObject before getting value?

Tags: java, json

I have JSONObject with a set of fields, not setting the field in JSONObject if it has a null value in the angular app. So I am doing a null check of each field before getting the value of that in spring-boot as below.

```
            JSONObject exclusionObj = (JSONObject) exclusionArray.get(i);
            SampleBean sample  = new SampleBean();

            if(exclusionObj.isNull("name")) {
                sample.setName(null);
            }else{
                sample.setName(exclusionObj.getString("name"));
            }

            if(exclusionObj.isNull("designation")) {
                sample.setDesignation(null);
            }else{
                sample.setdesignation(exclusionObj.getString("designation"));
            }

            if(exclusionObj.isNull("dept")) {
                sample.setDept(null);
            }else{
                sample.setDept(exclusionObj.getInt("dept"));
            }
```

Is there any better way to write this null check in a single statement instead of If-Else condition?

Comment: Why do you have to `sample.setName(null);` at all? Is `null` not the default?

Comment: null is the default value .. Instead of a blank line there I just added it for more understanding.

Comment: Just reverse the condition, only set if not null. `if (!exclusionObj.isNull("wtv")) sample.setWtv(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of if-else conditions by using below logic:

```
Iterator<String> keys = exclusionObj.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        if (!exclusionObj.isNull(keys.next())) {
            sample.setName(exclusionObj.getString(keys.next()));
        }
    }
```